# FreeMarker ?? operator treats missing value and false equally

Tags: freemarker

Using FreeMarker, faced such a thing. `??` operator treats missing value and `false`. For example, the following

```
<#assign someVar = false>
<#if someVar??>
    someVar exists!
<#else>
    someVar is empty...
</#if>
```

outputs:

```
someVar is empty...
```

Although I assume that `false` should be treated as existing value and thus output should be `someVar exists!`.

Is there some setting in FreeMarker that regulates such behavior? What is the best way to handle optional boolean values? (All is clear with strings like `stringVar!"default value"`, but this seem not to work with booleans). I need to handle optional boolean field, and output "Yes" for `true`, "No" for `false`, and "—" for empty value.

Answer (score 0):

`??` doesn't treat boolean values specially. `someVar??` means "someVar exist", and `false` does exists. What confuses you is that you believe that `??` has the opposite meaning ("someVar is missing").

Comment: ddekany, thank you for response. I've initially made a mistake in the code example in my question, now corrected it.
The point is, that someVar?? for value assigned to false returns false (!) in my case, by some reason (although, I assume that it should return true). So I'm trying to understand what can affect it, maybe some FreeMarker config setting or so (like with default boolean-to-string "?c" that can be changed in config),

Comment: Nothing I can think of should lead to this issue. On the implementation level, `??` just checks if the value is `null`, and nothing more. Can you try your example template on https://try.freemarker.apache.org?

Comment: Thank you ddekany, tried my template there, and it does work just fine (unlike in my environment where it fails). So now, I suppose there's some magic happening in my service where FreeMarker is built in. So no issue with FreeMarker. Thank you a lot for helping with figuring it out, my question is resolved now.